# Code Authorization Flow - why does it behave like implicit flow?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this Startup.cs which is taken basically from the MS project template. That should be Authorization Code Flow to authenticate with Azure Active Directory. But it throws an execption with the following message, which says it tries to be a implicit auth flow. But why? How can i force Auth Code Flow? Is there a working example?

I use ASP.NET MVC (NOT Core), 4.xxxx something. The most recent. And Owin.

I get this error: https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700054 and it when i debug, it does not execute "AuthorizationCodeReceived".

Current code:

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            string clientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"] + "/v2.0";
            string appKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
                    //Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    //ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // Simplification (see note below)
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                                code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you share the exception and the stacktrace?

Comment: I had to change "//ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken" to "OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code".

After that, it jumpgs into AutorizationCodeReceived but "context.AuthenticationTicket..." is null on line "string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket".

Idea whats wrong with that?

Or Maybe an example or authorization code flow with ASP.NET MVC (NOT CORE) with SingleOrg AAD Authentication?